# how can i sort a matrix's each row from smallest to largest and then find the matrix's peak value?

Tags: c#

i need to write a program that takes 1 to 100 integers randomly, then i need to take this program's transpose, then I need to sort this matrix (each row in itself) from smallest to largest.
and finally, i need to find this matrix's peak value. here is what i have written for the program. for now, it creates a random matrix (20x5) and then it takes its transpose. can you help me with finding its peak value and then sort its each row?

PS.: using classes is mandatory!

```
using System;

namespace my_matrix;
    class Program
    {
        public int[,] Create(int[,] myarray, int Row, int Clm)
        {
            Random value = new Random();
            myarray = new int[Row, Clm];
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (i < Row)
            {
                while (j < Clm)
                {
                    myarray[i, j] = value.Next(1, 100);
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
                j = 0;
            }

            return myarray;
        }
        public int[,] Print(int[,] myarray, int Row, int Clm)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=====ARRAY=====");
            for (int a = 0; a < Row; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < Clm; b++)
                {
                    Console.Write(myarray[a, b] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public int[,] Transpose(int[,] myarray, int Row, int Clm)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < Clm; b++)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < Row; a++)
                {
                    Console.Write(myarray[a, b] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return myarray;
        }
        public int[,] Print_Transpose(int[,] myarray, int Row, int Clm)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=====TRANSPOSE=====");

            for (int b = 0; b < Clm; b++)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < Row; a++)
                {
                    Console.Write(myarray[a, b] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return null;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Program x = new Program();
            int[,] myarray = new int[20, 5];
            int[,] a = x.Create(myarray, 20, 5);
            x.Print(a, 20, 5);
            x.Print_Transpose(a, 20, 5);


        }
    }
```

i don't know how to make a class which sorta each row from smallest to largest and also i dont know how to create a class which finds the matrix's peak value.

Comment: The peak value from each row? btw, you did not transpose anything, you only printed it transposed. Your array is stil same..

Comment: peak value of the whole matrix i guess... it takes its transpose btw there is nothing wrong with that

Answer (score 0):

You can run over the array, keeping the maxNum:

```
public int getMax(int[,] fromArray)
    {
        int maxNum = 0;
        for (int b = 0; b < fromArray.GetUpperBound(1); b++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < fromArray.GetUpperBound(0); a++)
            {
                if (maxNum < fromArray[a,b])
                {
                    maxNum = fromArray[a, b];
                }
            }
        }
        return maxNum;
    }
```

Call the function like:

```
Console.Write("Max number = {0:D}", x.getMax (a));
```

If you want a sort method, you can place all values in a List, sort them and convert back to array.

```
public int[] SortArray(int[,] fromArray)
    {
        List<int> newList = new List<int>(fromArray.Length);
        
        for (int b = 0; b < fromArray.GetUpperBound(1); b++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < fromArray.GetUpperBound(0); a++)
            {
                newList.Add (fromArray[a, b]);
            }
        }
        newList.Sort();
        return newList.ToArray<int>();
    }
```

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your answer! but sorting method is not working tho. what could be the problem? i couldnt find.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?